# Cannot get AWSS3PutObjectRequest in v2 AWS SDK to duplicate S3PutObjectRequest in v1 SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Having problems with the new Amazon SDK, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2

I'm just trying to write a file to an s3 bucket that already exists.  Here's the code that I can't get to work for some reason (even though it logs "success").

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"KEY" secretKey:@"SECRET_KEY"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

AWSS3 *s3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];

AWSS3PutObjectRequest *logFile = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest alloc];
logFile.bucket = @"test";
logFile.key = @"file2";
logFile.contentType = @"text/plain";
logFile.body = @"this is a test";
[[s3 putObject:logFile] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    NSLog(@"Totally did it");
    return nil;
}];
```

The prior SDK (v1.x) this worked, but I'm trying to switch over because I like Bolts framework functionality.

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"KEY" withSecretKey:@"SECRET_KEY"];
S3PutObjectRequest *logFile = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"file1" inBucket:@"test"];
logFile.contentType = @"text/plain";
    NSString* myStuff = @"this is a test";
NSData* log = [myStuff dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
logFile.data = log;
[s3 putObject:logFile];
```

Anyone out there playing with the new SDK who can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** - New Code Snippet

```
 AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:awsAccessKey secretKey:awsSecretKey];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

/* This section works but posts as text/xml
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *getLog = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
*/
AWSS3 *transferManager = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
AWSS3PutObjectRequest *getLog = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest alloc];
getLog.bucket = awsS3Bucket;
getLog.key = awsS3FileNameString;
getLog.contentType = @"text/plain";
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:logFileName];
long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
getLog.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
getLog.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

/* 
[[transferManager upload:getLog] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
*/

[[transferManager putObject:getLog] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {        
    if(task.error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Got here: %@", task.result);

    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `body` property of `AWSS3PutObjectRequest` needs to be either `NSURL` or `NSData`. If you convert the `NSString` to `NSData` like you are doing in v1 code snippet, it should work.

Comment: I'm still not getting it to putObject in the S3 bucket.  Using AWSS3TransferManager / AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest/ upload, I'm able to upload the file into the S3 bucket, however, it's always uploading as text/xml, regardless of contentType

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting in the put request. Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AZNetworkingErrorDomain Code=0 "Invalid AZURLSessionTaskType."

Comment: Added both versions I'm playing with, I just swap out the comment blocks depending on what I'm playing with.

Comment: You are not calling `init` on `AWSS3PutObjectRequest`. `AWSS3PutObjectRequest *getLog = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest alloc];` needs to be `AWSS3PutObjectRequest *getLog = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];`

Comment: My only comment at this point is that while the file is now correctly put into S3 bucket, it's always `text/xml`, regardless of the file extension and how I set the `getLog.contentType`

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda - You're right. Bloody copy&paste hell :)